# How to decide if a template class has a certain member function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a member-function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-member-functions-existenc)

I need a way to decide if a template class has some member function, so that I can call different specializations for a functions. For example, I have the following classes:

```
class A1 {
    void a() const { cout << "a1" << endl; }
};

class A2 {
    void a() const { cout << "a2" << endl; }
};

class B {
    void b() const { cout << "b" << endl; }
};
```

When I call my function with an instance of A1 or A2 as the template parameter, I want to call one overload (which can utilize `a()`), but if it doesn't exist, I can go without it.

I was looking at the standard and Boost type traits libraries, but found nothing like this. I basically want something like this:

```
template <class T>
typename enable_if<has_member<A, a>::value>::type
f(const T& t) {
    t.a();
}

template <class T>
typename enable_if<!has_member<A, a>::value>::type
f(const T&) {
    cout << "no a" << endl;
}
```

The problem is that I don't know of any `has_member` type traits, and I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: how and why do you need that? Couldn't you use template specialization for that, in a way that you do one version with calling a and another without calling a. and one of the template parameters shall distinguish which of the two you will actually take?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use member detection idiom for that 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector